# Using fixtures with factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory, fixtures, factory-bot

When building the following factory:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:name) { |n| "foo#{n}" }
  f.resume_type_id { ResumeType.first.id }
end
```

`ResumeType.first` returns **nil** and I get an error.

`ResumeType` records are loaded via fixtures. I checked using the console and the entries are there, the table is not empty.

I've found a similar example in the factory_girl mailing list, and it's supposed to work.

What am I missing? Do I have to somehow tell factory_girl to set up the fixtures before running the tests?

This is what my test_helper looks like:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")
require 'test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = false
  fixtures :all
end
```

Comment: Why use a mixture of factories and fixtures? Factories replace fixtures.

Comment: How does your test_helper.rb looks like?

Comment: I'm using fixtures for fixed data that won't be changed by anyone after it's seeded.

Comment: I added test_helper.rb to the question

Comment: In answer to the question of "why use a mixture of factories and fixtures", in my case? To get from one to the other in small steps.

Comment: @GraemeMathieson agreed! Another use case is when you want "singleton" or "memoized" fixtures whose id remains constant across references within the same test.  See also https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/148

Comment: In answer to the question of "why use a mixture of factories and fixtures", in my case? To delegate expensive construction of models to the much faster fixture system, in order to reduce the time tests take to run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution to this was to create a db/seeds.rb file which contained model code to generate my seed data:

```
# Create the user roles
Role.create(:name => "Master", :level => 99)
Role.create(:name => "Admin", :level => 80)
Role.create(:name => "Editor", :level => 40)
Role.create(:name => "Blogger", :level => 30)
Role.create(:name => "User", :level => 0)
```

And then include it in my spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..','config','environment'))
require 'spec/autorun'
require 'spec/rails'
require "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"
```

(To be fair, I haven't managed to get autospec to play nice with this yet as it keeps duplicating my seed data, but I haven't tried all that hard either.)

This also has the benefit of being Rails 3 ready and working with the rake db:seed task.

Comment: Your best bet is to create an idempotent db/seeds.rb file, so no matter how often it's run, it still gets towards the same end state. In your example, I'd do: `Role.find_or_create_by_name(:name => "Master", :level => 99)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add `seed.rb` in your `test` or `spec` directory and require it in your helper file before your factories:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/seed")
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/factories")
```

Rails 2.3